# Java: Load classes and referenced jars from a jar

Tags: java, jar, classpath

Imagine there is a jar (named **lib.jar**) that contains a single class and manifest file.

The class is MyLibClass1. MyLibClass1 class contains single public static method execute().

The manifest file has a line "Class-Path:" that reference other jar files (**jar1.jar** and **jar2.jar**)

MANIFEST.MF is in the META-INF of the **lib.jar** and contains:

Class-Path: jar1.jar jar2.jar

These jars are used in some project MyProject and are located in libs directory of it.

The project has a main class *Main* with method *main* and has only 1 line:

*MyLibClass1.execute();*

The problem is that when I try to invoke Main class of MyProject, JVM says that it is not able to find the MyLibClass1 class that **is** in the **lib.jar**.

java -cp libs/*;bin Main

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

*java -version*
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)

The libs folder contains **lib.jar**, **jar1.jar** and **jar2.jar**

There is a good comment about where is Main.class.
In fact the class in bin directory, so I have to change the java execution command.

java -cp libs/*;bin Main

Comment: make sure your `lib.jar,jar1.jar and jar2.jar` is inside WEB-INF/lib folder of your application

Comment: What's the output of java -version? Where is the Main class, and which jars are in the libs folder? Note: if you don't use the -jar option, the classpath of the manifest is not taken into account.

Comment: @Vivek: where have you seen that he has a webapp? He's trying to execute a main class, not to run a webapp.

Comment: @JB Nizet...ohhh yes man...i thought so...

Comment: Are you sure your imports are all correct?

Comment: the code is compiled (which means that imports are ok), but during execution I receive ClassNotFoundException which is of MyLibClass1 class that is in *lib.jar*

Comment: Try changing to `libs/*.jar` in the classpath, I can't quite remember if you have to specify jar "explicitly".

Comment: @Viruzzo according to the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html multiple jars/zips have to be supplied simply with libs/*

Comment: @Tim actually "For a .jar or .zip file that contains .class files, the class path ends with the name of the .zip or .jar file", so it's the opposite: they **require** you to use the filename (as I remembered).

Comment: @Viruzzo a bit below it is written: "Class path entries can contain the basename wildcard character *, which is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR. For example, the class path entry foo/* specifies all JAR files in the directory named foo. A classpath entry consisting simply of * expands to a list of all the jar files in the current directory."

Comment: @Tim my bad. Still, have you tried with all explicit file names?

Comment: @Viruzzo no, I did not tried with all expicit names, I have a feeling that the reason was the other one. For example, after removing the manifest from the **lib.jar** the problem disappered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by removing manifest from lib.jar file.

Therefore there is a bit confusing conclusion: **"Class-Path:" of a jar hides the classes of a jar itself.**

Welcome to disprove this statement.

Comment: @Viruzzo surely: *Class-Path: jar1.jar jar2.jar*

Comment: Did you have `Manifest-Version: 1.0` as the first line?

Comment: @Viruzzo yes, surely: *Manifest-Version: 1.0*

Comment: So the contents of lib.jar were `MyLibClass1.class` and `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, all in the correct case? I can't see any problem if this is the case.

Comment: @Viruzzo Exactly this is the case, but I have a problem described in the question. Don't you have the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

If current dir is `bin` then you should run `java -cp ".;../libs/*" Main`

Comment: the current folder is not *bin*. I have added bin folder in the java command (see an update)

Comment: If current folder was not bin then on `java -cp libs/* Main` JVM would complain that it can't find `Main` class, not `MyLibClass1`. So something is unclear in description. Try using the full path to lib to eliminate the chance that current dir is wrong.

Comment: exactly, that is why I have written and update and the command is java -cp libs/*;bin Main

Comment: That's still a relative path, try a full one.

Comment: @Viruzzo unfortunately does not help. Funny but the code is compiled and the ClassNotFoundException is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a semicolon after "bin".

`java -cp libs/*;bin; Main`